# Getting a blank string when I try print dl reference from a url within a loop

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have already created a loop that runs through the following results page   https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=SW181Db&page=1

I would now like to open the urls in results page in sequence and scrape the data from them. Example of results page, https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/08569390

I was hoping that by defining properties_col that by classifying the columns as per the code below it would generate the contents of the tags but its simply giving me, what i believe to be, a blank string [].  output in python is x 25

My full code is below. any ideas? thanks and regards

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
base_url = 'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/'

header={'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
 'Cookie':'mdtp=y4Ts2Vvql5V9MMZNjqB9T+7S/vkQKPqjHHMIq5jk0J1l5l131dU0YXsq7Rr15GDyghKHrS/qcD2vdsMCVtzKByJEDZFI+roS6tN9FN5IS70q8PkCCBjgFPDZjlR1A3H9FJ/zCWXMNJbaXqF8MgqE+nhR3/lji+eK4mm/GP9b8oxlVdupo9KN9SKanxu/JFEyNXutjyN+BsxRztNem1Z+ExSQCojyxflI/tc70+bXAu3/ppdP7fIXixfEOAWezmOh3ywchn9DV7Af8wH45t8u4+Y=; mdtpdi=mdtpdi#f523cd04-e09e-48bc-9977-73f974d50cea#1484041095424_zXDAuNhEkKdpRUsfXt+/1g==; seen_cookie_message=yes; _ga=GA1.4.666959744.1484041122; _gat=1',
'Host':'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/',
#'Referer':'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.51 Safari/537.36'
}

session = requests.session()
url = 'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=SW181Db&page=1'
response = session.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")     

rslt_table = soup.find_all('a', {'title': 'View company'})  

for elem in rslt_table:
    det_url = base_url+elem['href']
    print det_url
    response = session.get(det_url, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")
    properties_col = soup.find_all('dl',{'class':'column-two-thirds'})         
    print properties_col
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
base_url = 'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk'
```

- change the base url
- remove the slash at the end

First output:

```
https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/08569390
[<dl class="column-two-thirds">\n            <dt>Company status</dt>\n            <dd class="text data" id="company-status">\n                Dissolved\n            </dd>\n        </dl>, <dl class="column-two-thirds">\n            <dt>Company type</dt>\n            <dd class="text data" id="company-type">\n                Private limited Company\n            </dd>\n        </dl>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
base_url = 'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/'
href = '/company/08569390'
urljoin(base_url, href)
```

out:

```
'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/08569390'
```

you have an extra `/` in the `base_url`, use `urljoin` to avoid this problem.

if you use `+` in the url, the output is:

```
'https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk//company/08569390'
```